# Ruby server +ActionScript3

Tags: ruby, actionscript

I'm using WebSocket on ruby server.

```
require          'em-websocket'

def start_server(host, port)
  EM.run {
    EM::WebSocket.run(:host => host, :port => port) do |ws|
      ws.onopen {

      }
      ws.onmessage {
      }
      ws.onclose {

      }
    end
    puts 'Server is running at' + Time.now().to_s
  }
end
```

I need to send request with xml data from ActionScript client. How I can do it?
Thank you.

Comment: So this is an ActionScript question?